# Jquery AutoNumeric does not work when form is a LIVE form

Tags: jquery, ajax, input, currency

I made an input-control of an input field with "auto numeric".
[AutoNumeric Website](https://github.com/BobKnothe/autoNumeric)

It works well in normal mode, but when I load the content (with form) live through ajax it does not work. Do somebody have an idea?

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.price').autoNumeric('init');
});
```

Comment: did you manage to solve the problem? I've got the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Use `update` method

```
$('#sum-1').autoNumeric("update" ,{});
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd suggest using the latest `v4` which has seen a **LOT** of improvement since the old `1.9` era.

Second, since you are I imagine directly updating the input value via another script, you need to make AutoNumeric aware of this change.
The best way to do that is to use the element `set()` function to set the new value.
Example :

```
const newValue = ajaxCall();
aNElement.set(newValue);
```

...and you're done ;)